# WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details (Connection errror in webRTC)

Tags: javascript, python, webrtc, django-channels, turn

I have been trying to create a real time video chat app using webrtc and django. While trying to establish a peer to peer connection, an error as "WebRTC: ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details" keeps on coming. I'm new to WebRTC. Am I missing something or is there any other approach to do this? I'm testing this on firefox.

```
const created = '{{created}}';
  const room = "{{room}}";
  let isCreated;

  let iceServers = {
        iceServers: [
          { urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com" },
          { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" },
        ],
      };

  const constraints = {
    'video' : true,
    'audio' : true
  };

  var loc = window.location;
  console.log(loc);
  var wsStart = 'ws://'

  if (loc.protocol == 'https:'){
    wsStart = 'wss://'
  }

  var endPoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname;
  console.log(endPoint);

  webSocket = new WebSocket(endPoint);
```

I tried to setup a turn server using coTURN, but the server is not working properly. It will be great if someone could guide me.